# IF function in DropDownList\CoboBox

Tags: autohotkey

i want to make `LShift` in ComboBox become a `<+`,when i tap a batton. But `IF` function in `LB11` is not working.

```
toggle1 := !toggle1
    Gui, Add, Button, x0 w175 y469 Default, Save
    Gui, Add, Button, x+1 w175 y469 Default, Exit
    Gui, Add, Tab, x0 y0 w350 h468, System|Chrome|three

    Gui, Tab, System
        Gui, Add, Button, x10 y52 w23 h23 gEdit1  vEdit1, 1
        Gui, Add, Text, x37 y39 vbtxt11, %LB11%+%LB12%+%LB13%

            Gui, Add, ComboBox, +hidden  x36 y32 w50 gLM11 vLB11 AltSubmit, LShift|RShift|LCtrl|RCtrl|LAlt|RAlt|LWin|Rwin

    Gui, show, w351 h493
    return

    Edit1:
        if toggle1
        {
            GuiControl, Show, LB11
            GuiControl, Hide, btxt11
        }
        else 
        {
            GuiControl, Hide, LB11
            GuiControl, Show, btxt11
        }
    toggle1 := not toggle1 
    return
    Gui, Tab
    ButtonExit:
        ExitApp
    ButtonSave:
        Gui, Submit, Nohide 
        GuiControl,,btxt11, %LB11%+%LB12%+%LB13%

        IniWrite, %LB11%, E:\Reserve\AHK scrpts\exemples\4RS\partm.ini, key1, LB11

        LM11:
    if (LB11 = 1)
    {
       ;<<< here is a problem
    }
```

**what i want:**

i choose `LShift` in combobox.

`LShift`  become `<+`.

`<+`  must be saved in `.ini` file.

when press the button i have a `<+`, **not** `LShift`.

**what happening:**

i choose `LShift` in combobox.

`LShift` saving in `.ini` file.

when press the button i have a `LShift`, **not** `<+`.

**Full Script:**

1) [Script](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1w_BTLFe4SUkM93Cl3B5RDsEKw5Mq_yQO)
2) [.ini File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XDYEIlf30Vz98gJfzBGJPeQUs8Un8Zr-)

**Short version:**

1) [Script](https://drive.google.com/open?id=12f3lxhMfloz50CTNMFKegTEn3FNAZTn_)
2) [.ini File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1t9mbVVvnCM1dHf7fEmwVNeUGZvKxlbsw)

Comment: Why do you want to `<+` instead of `LShift`? `LShift` works just fine as a hotkey definition if that's what you we're worried about. Otherwise, you're going to have to make your own replacement method for doing that. There's no pre-made function or command in ahk for that (as far as I know).

Comment: script in post is working. just put "LM11" before "GuiControl,,btxt11, %LB11%+%LB12%+%LB13%"

``^numpad1::

Syskey1++

if Syskey1 = 3 

{
 Send ^{v}
 Syskey1 = 0
}

SetTimer, Syskey1raction2, -200 
return

Syskey1raction2:

 if Syskey1 = 2

{
  Send ^{x}
  Syskey1 = 0
}
SetTimer, Syskey1raction3, -100

return

Syskey1raction3:
if Syskey1 = 1
{
  Send %LB111%{%LB131%}  ; ^{c}
  Syskey1 = 0
}
return``

script in post must be a redactor of this one. and it is not work. output is

Comment: I thought that problem was in uotput `LShift` \ `LCtrl` and other, then  i try to make him as `<+`. but that still not work. and then i tried to summ two variables in one, but ahk don't like `<+` or the same, he say that it is illigal character.